# Create SARIF File to be uploaded to from dotnet build to be loaded to Github using codeql-action/upload-sarif@v2

Tags: c#, github-actions, .net-7.0

I am having difficulty building my project so that I can produce a SARIF file from the compiler doing dotnet build.

I have been trying variations of this command I found.

```
dotnet build MyProject.csproj --configuration Release -p:RunCodeAnalysis=true -p:ClOptions="/analyze:log%20MyProject.nativecodeanalysis.combined.sarif"
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of issues I ended up having to do a couple things.

1. Make sure the project has a package reference to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` or set property `EnableNETAnalyzers` to true

```xml
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="7.0.3" PrivateAssets="all" />
```

2. Either add the following properties or reference them in your build command.

```xml
    <AnalysisMode>all</AnalysisMode>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest-all</AnalysisLevel>
    <ErrorLog>BuildOutput.sarif,version=2.1</ErrorLog>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreGeneratedCode>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreGeneratedCode>
```

or

```
dotnet build MyProject.csproj --configuration Release -p:AnalysisMode=all -p:AnalysisLevel=latest-all -p:ErrorLog="BuildOutput.sarif,version=2.1"
```

That should all work locally.  There is another [issue](https://github.com/github/codeql-action/issues/418) on github where the dotnet command produces a bad value for language.  `instance.runs[0].tool.driver.language does not match pattern "^[a-zA-Z]{2}|^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}]?$"`

To resolve that I added the `PreferredUILang` tag.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup .NET
        id: setup
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0.x
      - name: Run Build
        run: |
            & dotnet build src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj --configuration Release -p:AnalysisMode=all -p:AnalysisLevel=latest-all -p:'ErrorLog=\"${{ github.workspace }}/BuildOutput.sarif,version=2.1\"' -p:EnableNETAnalyzers=true -p:'PreferredUILang=\"en-US\"' --no-incremental
        shell: pwsh
      - name: Upload SARIF file
        if: '!cancelled()'
        uses: github/codeql-action/upload-sarif@v2
        with:
          sarif_file: BuildOutput.sarif
```

Comment: I am getting this error in Azure DevOps pipelines and then empty report:
Pre-SARIF-2.1 logs have been omitted. Use the Artifacts explorer to access all files.

It seems that the version is not being picked up?!

Comment: Thanks @Niederee, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve.